# Redirect from /folder/index.php to /folder/

Tags: php

I am trying to get my website to redirect to

`www.domain.tld/folder/`

from

`www.domain.tld/folder/index.php?params=blah&param2=etc`

I have tried:

`header("Location: /")`

But all it does is redirect me to

`www.domain.tld`

Does anyone know how to redirect properly to just the folder?

Comment: Have you thought about using your .htaccess file to do this?

Comment: @Leptonator I don't want every page to do it...Only some. I use the params to redirect around, then, at the final page, i just want it to change to /folder/

Comment: `header('Location: http://www.domain.tld/folder/')` ?

Comment: @phil it a dynamic domain

Comment: try `header("Location: /folder/")` then

Comment: @DipeshParmar its dynamic, so the folder changes. Essentially, this is for my login php file. You can login from most pages, and pages are in different folders.

Comment: @Asryael So use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

Comment: `header("location: ./");`

Comment: @JasonOOO THANK YOU!!! Can't believe it was that easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`header("location: ./");`

will do the job, but you will face infinite redirection because of index.php if there is no `if` condition for specific case such as `?params=blah&param2=etc`

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the above answer you can place check for query string in the index.php as

```
 <?php
      if ( ($_GET['params'] == 'blah') && ($_GET['param2'] == 'etc') ) {
           header("location: ./");
           exit;
      }  
 ?>
```